# SharePoint is not installed

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 with only one pack: "Office/SharePoint development" and now I want to create new project.

Steps which I do:
File -> New Project -> Installed -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Office/SharePoint -> SharePoint Solutions -> SharePoint 2013 - Visual Web Part.

And I get an error like the following:
The required version of SharePoint Foundation or SharePoint Server is not installed on this system. The target version of the SharePoint project is 15.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm learning SharePoint development as well and also stumbled upon this issue.

Assuming you have all the requirements needed for developing SharePoint including having SharePoint installed on the same machine, my guess is that you are choosing a project template that does not match your installed SharePoint version.

Since you chose the template SharePoint 2013-Visual Web Part and the error message is indicating the target version is 15.0, you should ensure you have SharePoint 2013 installed and not 2010 or 2016.  Or if you do have SharePoint 2010 or 2016 installed, then ensure you are choosing the proper template.  Example:  SharePoint 2016 - Visual Web Part